# Bump Python package version upon main branch merge

Tags: python, git, github, version, semantic-versioning

## My Problem

I am developing a Python package consumed by several internal consumers in my company using their CI/CD pipeline. Therefore, it's important for them to know what is the latest version of the package so that they can install it if it has been changed. The package uses the classic [PEP 440 SemVer structure](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#semantic-versioning), so I usually just update the minor number.

I'm using Git and GitHub, so every new commit to the main branch means a new version. I'm currently updating the version manually, which is error-prone and tedious. I'm looking for a way to automatically bump the minor version whenever I merge a PR to the main branch.

## What Have I Tried

- Manual version bump before the merge
- Using [bump2version](https://github.com/c4urself/bump2version/#installation) - I don't know how to make it happen automatically on a merge to the main branch

## My Question

How can I automatically bump the minor version of a Python package upon a PR merged to the main branch of a repo?

Comment: Take a look at [github actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions). They let you define a trigger (i.e. "every push to `master`") and actions you want to take, like calling `bump2version` and committing/pushing that change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using bump2version locally, you can add to your GitHub repostory the [`bump2version-action`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/bump2version-action), which states:

> Every time you merge something to main branch, you'll receive an additional direct commit to main that increments the version in `version.md`.

Example:

```yaml
name: Bump version workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    paths-ignore:
    - version.md

jobs:
  bump-version:
    name: Bump package version
    if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'Bump version')"
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - name: actions/checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
          persist-credentials: false
    - name: current_version
      run: echo "current_version=$(grep '# version' version.md | cut -d ' ' -f3)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: FragileTech/bump-version
      uses: FragileTech/bump-version@main
      with:
        current_version: "${{ env.current_version }}"
        files: version.md
        commit_name: Your Company Bot
        commit_email: bot@your-company.com
        login: your-bot-login
        token: "${{ secrets.BOT_TOKEN }}"
```

---

As noted by [C S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175053/c-s) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936534/bump-python-package-version-upon-main-branch-merge/70937034#comment130010719_70937034):

> You can use `part` as an input argument.
> OP wanted to bump the minor version automatically on merge, not the patch version, which is the default with no part arg for this action.

Comment: you can use `part` as an input arg.  OP wanted to bump the minor version automatically on merge, not the patch version, which is the default with no `part` arg for this action.

Comment: @CS Good point, thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @VonC for your elegant solution - it works beautifully :-)

(On same dev team as @AdamMatan)

Just one tweak we found necessary:

```yaml
    on:
      push:
        branches:
        - master
        paths-ignore:
        - version.md
```

Without this (or equivalent "action filter") - this action will perpetually self trigger in a "github fork bomb" :-)